# Aquamacs-emacs on OS X asks for error report even after complete reinstall

Tags: macos, emacs, aquamacs

I was using Aquamacs-emacs on OS X 10.5.x as my primary text editor and it crashed when I maxed out my RAM and other stuff (i think thats why).

When I tried to restart it, it asked about sending an error report. No matter what I did, the program wouldn't start, it just kept crashing. So i deleted the package/app, as well as the preferences/preference panes in both the user folder and the system folder.

Then I downloaded a new `dmg` and reinstalled.

The new package still asked about crashing/sending error report. **Where could this info be stored?**

---

I deleted stuff in the above mentioned folders and also 'application support' I think. I did have an issue with some type of malware recently but did an archive & reinstall (so the 'user' folder was transferred to the new system). I know for a fact that text files were opened/looked at remotely, so I was wondering if some sort of 3rd party functionality could have been added to emacs package to notify of changes to documents. Perhaps a hidden file somewhere?

Or am I overreacting, and failed to delete something that would do this naturally?

Comment: @whoever: after the reinstall of the program i can get it to work, but i had to click 'yes' on the 'send error report.'  I tried clicking 'no' a few times but nothing happened. weirdness

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will work, but Check and see if you have an errant ~/.emacs file, or anything wonky in ~/.emacs.d/